# implode(): Invalid arguments passed in

Tags: php, mysql

```
 $fields_arr = "SHOW FIELDS FROM 'payslip' WHERE FIELD NOT IN ('ID','Tax_Number','Employee_Number','Payslip_Number','Salary','Bonus','  Housing_Allowance','House1','Transport_Allowance','Travel_Allowance','Vehicle_Allowance','  Vehicle1','Cellphone_Allowance','   Entertainment_Allowance','  Company_Car','  Medical_Allowance','DSocial_Security',' DHousing_Allowance','DCompany_Car','DContributions','Other_Deductions','DVehicle_Allowance','Other_Allowance','Total_Income','Taxable_Income','Tax_Payable','Overtime','Overtime_Hours','Payday','Pension','Provident_Fund','Retirement_Annuity','Study_Policy','Month','Year','Company')";

$result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $fields_arr);
$fields = implode(',',$result3);
```

The error comes from the above code as i thing an array is not passed but another form of data type any help on the problem ?error i get is  "implode(): Invalid arguments passed "

```
$dql = "SELECT $fields FROM $tb2_name WHERE Month='$month' AND Year='$year' AND Employee_Number='$user' ";
```

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues).

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You must first fetch the data with for example `mysqli_fetch_assoc`:

```
$fields_arr = "SHOW FIELDS FROM 'payslip' WHERE FIELD NOT IN ('ID','Tax_Number','Employee_Number','Payslip_Number','Salary','Bonus','  Housing_Allowance','House1','Transport_Allowance','Travel_Allowance','Vehicle_Allowance','  Vehicle1','Cellphone_Allowance','   Entertainment_Allowance','  Company_Car','  Medical_Allowance','DSocial_Security',' DHousing_Allowance','DCompany_Car','DContributions','Other_Deductions','DVehicle_Allowance','Other_Allowance','Total_Income','Taxable_Income','Tax_Payable','Overtime','Overtime_Hours','Payday','Pension','Provident_Fund','Retirement_Annuity','Study_Policy','Month','Year','Company')";

$result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $fields_arr);
$arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conn, $result3);
$fields = implode(',',$arr);
```